# What am I looking at?

Tags: identify-this-bike

So, my neighbors husband passed and gave this to me. He was an avid rider. What am I looking at? Across the frame, looks like a sticker that once said Peddle Power on it with Shimano XT gear all around. [image]

Comment: It's a bike, yellow, I think.  Appears to be decent quality.  Appears (without seeing it up close) to be a 24" bike.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. Please be aware that this site gets a lot of identification requests, but it's often impossible to identify make and model. Exact make and model often does not really matter if you identify style, frame material, componentry etc.

Comment: Rear tyre seems to say 26x2.00

Comment: If you already have a bike, then this one could be an excellent shopper with some saddlebags, or it could be a great start as a winter beater bike by adding mudguards or snow tyres.  Certainly an eyecatching colour!

Comment: And as we all know, the correct number of bikes to own is n+1

Answer (score 2):

This is something built from mismatched parts. The frame looks like it's from the 90s with cable stops for cantilever brakes, threaded headset and quick release seatpost. Lugged construction hints that it was a high end one, but identifying the brand is going to be difficult. The drivetrain on the other hand is newer (probably late 00s) and second highest tier from Shimano.

And yes, the sticker really is misspelled.

Comment: I own a 2005 Cannondale Comfort 400 which is a hybrid and this. Don't want both. Is this sellable and what would be a good price point? and should I keep this or the Cannondale? I ride both off road and road and have always liked the Cannondale.

Comment: Cannondale is a feather compared to the "peddle power"

Comment: Or should I remove the Shimano Deore Gear from the mismatch bike and upgrade the Cannondale?

Comment: Thanks any help is appreciated. I have very limited knowledge on bicycles.

Comment: Moving the parts to the Cannondale is probably doable but you'll need to do some homework and get some tools to do it. Old steel bikes generally aren't worth much especially if you don't know the model, but exact valuations depend on location and everything so we can't give any valuations.

Comment: Cranks are Shimano M760 series XT from 2002-6, which is not really 'fairly new'

Comment: @peter Valuation are off topic here. It's worth whatever someone will pay you for it.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus to me the cranks look like Hollowtech II, which makes them at least 2005 and up to date with latest technical standard that fits BSA frames. But I agree, 2005 isn't that new any more.

Answer (score 0):

I like the ride it for a while before deciding to be rid of it idea.  You will have a better idea of the path you wish to take.  Older 26" non suspended steel frame MTB's are absolutely bullet proof and usually set up with good brakes and derailleur systems.  Good durable all round bicycles.  I also like hybrid bicycles so you have a tough job figuring out what to do.  I have found that bicycle weight is not a good predictor of overall performance.  Unless the bicycle is grossly heavy a few pounds is not going to make much of a difference in performance on properly maintained bicycles.  Good luck.

Comment: The difference between 15lbs and 18lbs is quite significant; the difference between 50lbs and 53lbs is basically nothing. So I think you have it exactly backwards when you say that "[u]nless the bicycle is grossly heavy a few pounds is not going to make much of a difference".

Comment: This is the difference when you lift the bike. When you ride it, you need to add your own weight to get meaningful results. For adult men it's usually from 100lbs upwards.